# HTML scraper output stuck in utf-8

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, character-encoding

I'm working on a scraper for a number of chinese documents. As part of the project I'm trying to scrape the body of the document into a list and then write an html version of the document from that list (the final version will include metadata as well as the text, along with a folder full of individual html files for the documents).

I've managed to scrape the body of the document into a list and then use the contents of that list to create a new HTML document.  I can even view the contents when I output the list to a csv (so far so good....). 
Unfortunately the HTML document that is output is all `"\u6d88\u9664\u8d2b\u56f0\u3001\"`.

Is there a way to encode the output so that this won't happen?  Do I just need to grow up and scrape the page for real (parsing and organizing it `<p>` by `<p>` instead of just copying all of the exiting HTML as is) and then build the new HTML page element by element?

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
#csv is for the csv writer
import csv

#initiates the dictionary to hold the output

holder = []

#this is the target URL
target_url = "http://www.gov.cn/zhengce/content/2016-12/02/content_5142197.htm"

data = []

filename = "fullbody.html"
target = open(filename, 'w')

def bodyscraper(url):
    #opens the url for read access
    this_url = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    #creates a new BS holder based on the URL
    soup = BeautifulSoup(this_url, 'lxml')

    #finds the body text
    body = soup.find('td', {'class':'b12c'})


    data.append(body)

    holder.append(data)

    print holder[0]
    for item in holder:
        target.write("%s\n" % item)

bodyscraper(target_url)


with open('bodyscraper.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(holder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the source htm is utf-8 encoded, when using bs just decoding what urllib returns which will work. I have tested both of html and csv output will show Chinese characters, here is the amended code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
#csv is for the csv writer
import csv

#initiates the dictionary to hold the output

holder = []

#this is the target URL
target_url = "http://www.gov.cn/zhengce/content/2016-12/02/content_5142197.htm"

data = []

filename = "fullbody.html"
target = open(filename, 'w')

def bodyscraper(url):
    #opens the url for read access
    this_url = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    #creates a new BS holder based on the URL
    soup = BeautifulSoup(this_url.decode("utf-8"), 'lxml') #decoding urllib returns

    #finds the body text
    body = soup.find('td', {'class':'b12c'})
    target.write("%s\n" % body) #write the whole decoded body to html directly


    data.append(body)

    holder.append(data)


bodyscraper(target_url)


with open('bodyscraper.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(holder)
```

Comment: This worked for the csv but the html still gave me (a new kind) of garbage output.  However, adding the line '<meta charset="utf-8"/>' to the start of the html gave me exactly what I wanted.